# looping in java for a certain duration and certain task

Tags: java, loops

I have a requirement as follows

```
loop(N times)
{
for(1 minute)
{
 write certain values to a tree map
}
for(exactly after that above 1 min task)
{
 serialize the tree map
 return the tree map
 create a new tree map
}
}
```

How do i attain this?

This is what i have done so far..

```
public class StoreMessage {
     private static long start_nanotime=System.nanoTime();
     private static Thread thisThread = Thread.currentThread();
     private static int timeToRun = 60000; // 1 minute
     private static byte[] b=null;
     public static Map <Long,Message> map1=new TreeMap<Long,Message>();

     public static byte[] store(Message message){

         new Thread(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
                 try{
                    sleep(timeToRun);
                    thisThread.interrupt();
                    b=serializer.serialize(map1);
                    new TreeMap<Long,Message>();
                 } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }
         }).start();

         while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            long precise_time=TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(System.currentTimeMillis())+(System.nanoTime()-start_nanotime);
            map1.put(precise_time, message);
         }
         return b;
     }
}
```

I was attempting to store all the JMS object of the class Message recieved in one minute into a tree map against its precise time as key.After completion of one minute, I wish to serialize the map and return the byte[] to another class. Meanwhile I create a new tree map to store the next set of JMS messages for a minute
This code is some how not working. It is giving me error of **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**. Also I noticed that it keeps writing only one message to the map, ie if the messages were "hi","good day to you"--these are two jms messages; the StoreMessage class recieves one message at a time..ie it would first receive "hi" and once this message is processed, then it would retrieve the next message. But what i noticed is, for one whole minute, when the thread is not interrupted, it writes only the first message to the map and gives an error. How do i fix these?

Comment: By reading the [corresponding Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) [and Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29) first?

Comment: One minute is 60 second. So while time diff is lower then 60 sec. do some operation.

Comment: At least write some Java first, this is just pseudocode so arguably isn't even a Java question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish in your code but I thought I'd at least give some feedback on it.

First off, you are running out of memory because you are in a spin loop calling:

```
map1.put(precise_time, message);
```

This will fill memory *very* quickly.  Modern computers are fast enough to create at least a million tree elements *per second*.  You are going to need to somehow limit the number of `put` calls you make.

Next, it is *very* strange to fork a thread so you can `interrupt()` the parent thread at a later time.  Instead, I would do something like the following which sets up a stop-at-time-millis value and then runs until the time is reached.  This gets rid of the `Thread` entirely.

```
long runUntilMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeToRunMillis;
while (true) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (now >= runUntilMillis) {
       break;
    }
    long precise_time = ...
    map1.put(precise_time, message);
}
return serializer.serialize(map1);
```

Some other thoughts:

- Your `precise_time` calculation is incorrect.  You can't take the number of milliseconds since epoch and add them into the `System` nano-second value.  You are likely to overflow the `long` if I'm not mistaken.  Actually, the nanosecond calculation would have been a negative value so I'm not sure what you were trying to do there.  I would just use `start_nanotime - System.nanoTime()`.
- You can't do `b = serializer.serialize(map1);` in the inner `Thread`.  That won't even compile since `b` had to either be defined inside of the thread or be `final`.
- I don't understand the like `new TreeMap<Long,Message>();` in the inner `Thread` which would just create a `TreeMap` that would have been immediately marked as garbage since you didn't assign it to anyone.  Maybe you meant to use `map1.clear()`?
- You are putting the same `message` value into every element in the `TreeMap`.  Not sure that is what you intended.

Comment: Hi Gray! Thank you for your response.. this code does not give me any error but it does not give me any output either.. Please help me!

Comment: Sorry @kuks.  Which code?  My code?  What does of output were you expecting?

Comment: Hi again Gray! Well, if this code were to work correctly, it was expected of it return the byte[] to another class which is calling it. That class is supposed to write this byte[] to an opaque dataset of the HDF5 database and create a file with h5 extension. I know for sure that the there is no error in the calling class for I have executed it quite a few time before.. This class code is basically supposed to connect my JMS structure and the HDF5 database. Please Gray..help me..I need it badly!

Comment: I'm afraid @kuks that you are now on your own.  If you want to ask another question about that stuff then fine.  Hope my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem you will need to work with Date type.

To improve the Date type, you may use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), or simple arithmetic.

`new Date()` - create an instance of Date for current moment.

```
Date date1 = new Date();
Thread.sleep(4000); //Do nothing for 4 sec
Date date2 = new Date(); 

long timeDiffInMs = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
```

The value of timeDiffInMs should be more less representing 4 sec.